# How to avoid adding information when exporting CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I try to export some data (45k rows) in a CSV file, like this :

```
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$extractFilename);

    // Open the standard output stream for writing additional Open
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'a');

    foreach ($arrayExtract as $k => $v) {
        fputcsv($fp, $v, ';');
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_end_clean();
```

In the end of file I have the code HTML of the current page !!

I added an **exit;** in the end of my function in order to stop writing in file, I got this error in my chrome browser (no problem on firefox) :

[image]

The message in english : **network error**

Any idea ?

Thank's in advance !

Comment: How about...not echoing HTML at the end of your script. Just a thought... :-). i.e. if you know the request is for downloading a CSV, then simply use an if/else to control which output is generated (HTML or CSV). Or move the code which generates the CSV into a separate PHP script and only call that script.

Comment: P.S. `Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel;` is inaccurate. You're outputting a CSV file, not an Excel file. It should be `text/csv` instead of `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

Comment: @ADyson, thank's ! I resolved the problem with adding if/else  to control wich output will be generated. If the output is CSV, I return an empty response (return new Response()) instead of exit;